# How to use bpf_probe_read() to copy large length data in EBPF program?

Tags: ebpf, bpf

I am trying to dump the contents of the user space buffer in `write()` system call by running ebpf programs on `tracepoint/syscalls/sys_enter_write`.
I want to copy data with a maximum length of 1024, so I use `BPF_MAP_TYPE_PERCPU_ARRAY` to temporarily store the expected data structure, but when reading data through `bpf_probe_read`, I get an error from the verifier: `load program: permission denied: 11: (63) *(u32 *) (r2 +0) = r1: R2 invalid mem access 'inv' (21 line(s) omitted)`.

kernel: 5.4.119

```c
#include "vmlinux.h"
#include "common.h"
#include "bpf_tracing.h"
#include "bpf_helpers.h"

char __license[] SEC("license") = "Dual MIT/GPL";

struct {
    __uint(type, BPF_MAP_TYPE_PERCPU_ARRAY);
    __uint(max_entries, 1);
    __type(key, __u32);
    __type(value, struct syscall_write_event_t);
} write_buffer_heap SEC(".maps");

struct {
    __uint(type, BPF_MAP_TYPE_PERF_EVENT_ARRAY);
} syscall_write_events SEC(".maps");

#define MAX_MSG_SIZE 1024
// This needs to match exactly with the Go version of the struct.
struct syscall_write_event_t {
    struct attr_t {
        int event_type;
        int fd;
        int bytes;
        // Care needs to be taken as only msg_size bytes of msg are guaranteed
        // to be valid.
        int msg_size;
      } attr;
    char msg[MAX_MSG_SIZE];
};

struct sys_enter_read_write_ctx {
    __u64 __unused_syscall_header;
    __u32 __unused_syscall_nr;

    __u64 fd;
    const char * buf;
    size_t count;
};

enum {
  kEventTypeSyscallAddrEvent = 1,
  kEventTypeSyscallWriteEvent = 2,
  kEventTypeSyscallCloseEvent = 3,
};

SEC("tracepoint/syscalls/sys_enter_write")
int syscall__probe_write(struct sys_enter_read_write_ctx *ctx) {
    int zero = 0;
    struct syscall_write_event_t *event = bpf_map_lookup_elem(&write_buffer_heap, &zero);
    if (!event) {
      return 0;
    }

    __builtin_memset(&event, 0, sizeof(event));
    event->attr.fd = ctx->fd;
    event->attr.bytes = ctx->count;
//    size_t buf_size = ctx->count < sizeof(event->msg) ? ctx->count : sizeof(event->msg);
//    size_t buf_size = ctx->count < 0x400 ? ctx->count : 0x3ff;
    size_t buf_size = ctx->count & 0x3ff;
//    asm volatile("%[buf_size] &= 0xfff;\n" ::[buf_size] "+r"(buf_size) :);
    bpf_probe_read(&event->msg, buf_size, ctx->buf);
    event->attr.msg_size = buf_size;
    event->attr.event_type = kEventTypeSyscallWriteEvent;

    bpf_perf_event_output(ctx, &syscall_write_events, BPF_F_CURRENT_CPU, &event, sizeof(event->attr) + buf_size);
    return 0;
}
```

`llvm-objdump -d -S --no-show-raw-insn -l  --symbolize-operands syscalls_bpfel_x86.o`

```
sock_bpfel_x86.o:       file format elf64-bpf

Disassembly of section tracepoint/syscalls/sys_enter_write:

0000000000000000 <syscall__probe_write>:
; syscall__probe_write():
       0:       r6 = r1
       1:       r1 = 0
       2:       *(u32 *)(r10 - 4) = r1
       3:       r2 = r10
; syscall_write_events():
       4:       r2 += -4
       5:       r1 = 0 ll
       7:       call 1
       8:       if r0 == 0 goto +10 <LBB0_2>
       9:       r1 = *(u64 *)(r6 + 16)
      10:       r2 = 4
      11:       *(u32 *)(r2 + 0) = r1
      12:       r2 = *(u64 *)(r6 + 32)
      13:       r1 = 8
      14:       *(u32 *)(r1 + 0) = r2
      15:       r3 = *(u64 *)(r6 + 24)
      16:       r2 &= 1023
      17:       r1 = 16
      18:       call 4

0000000000000098 <LBB0_2>:
; LBB0_2():
      19:       r0 = 0
      20:       exit
```

verifier log:

```
 func#0 @0
0: R1=ctx(id=0,off=0,imm=0) R10=fp0
; int syscall__probe_write(struct sys_enter_read_write_ctx *ctx) {
0: (bf) r6 = r1
1: R1=ctx(id=0,off=0,imm=0) R6_w=ctx(id=0,off=0,imm=0) R10=fp0
1: (b7) r1 = 0
2: R1_w=inv0 R6_w=ctx(id=0,off=0,imm=0) R10=fp0
; int zero = 0;
2: (63) *(u32 *)(r10 -4) = r1
last_idx 2 first_idx 0
regs=2 stack=0 before 1: (b7) r1 = 0
3: R1_w=invP0 R6_w=ctx(id=0,off=0,imm=0) R10=fp0 fp-8=0000????
3: (bf) r2 = r10
4: R1_w=invP0 R2_w=fp0 R6_w=ctx(id=0,off=0,imm=0) R10=fp0 fp-8=0000????
;
4: (07) r2 += -4
5: R1_w=invP0 R2_w=fp-4 R6_w=ctx(id=0,off=0,imm=0) R10=fp0 fp-8=0000????
; struct syscall_write_event_t *event = bpf_map_lookup_elem(&write_buffer_heap, &zero);
5: (18) r1 = 0xffff888802a72000
7: R1_w=map_ptr(id=0,off=0,ks=4,vs=1040,imm=0) R2_w=fp-4 R6_w=ctx(id=0,off=0,imm=0) R10=fp0 fp-8=0000????
7: (85) call bpf_map_lookup_elem#1
8: R0_w=map_value_or_null(id=1,off=0,ks=4,vs=1040,imm=0) R6_w=ctx(id=0,off=0,imm=0) R10=fp0 fp-8=mmmm????
; if (!event) {
8: (15) if r0 == 0x0 goto pc+10
 R0_w=map_value(id=0,off=0,ks=4,vs=1040,imm=0) R6_w=ctx(id=0,off=0,imm=0) R10=fp0 fp-8=mmmm????
9: R0_w=map_value(id=0,off=0,ks=4,vs=1040,imm=0) R6_w=ctx(id=0,off=0,imm=0) R10=fp0 fp-8=mmmm????
; event->attr.fd = ctx->fd;
9: (61) r1 = *(u32 *)(r6 +16)
10: R0_w=map_value(id=0,off=0,ks=4,vs=1040,imm=0) R1_w=inv(id=0,umax_value=4294967295,var_off=(0x0; 0xffffffff)) R6_w=ctx(id=0,off=0,imm=0) R10=fp0 fp-8=mmmm????
10: (b7) r2 = 4
11: R0_w=map_value(id=0,off=0,ks=4,vs=1040,imm=0) R1_w=inv(id=0,umax_value=4294967295,var_off=(0x0; 0xffffffff)) R2_w=inv4 R6_w=ctx(id=0,off=0,imm=0) R10=fp0 fp-8=mmmm????
; event->attr.fd = ctx->fd;
11: (63) *(u32 *)(r2 +0) = r1
R2 invalid mem access 'inv'
```

I removed `__builtin_memset`, then i got `invalid stack type R4 off=-24 access_size=1039`

```c
SEC("tracepoint/syscalls/sys_enter_write")
int syscall__probe_write(struct sys_enter_read_write_ctx *ctx) {
    int zero;

    size_t buf_size = ctx->count < 0x400 ? ctx->count : 0x3ff;
    asm volatile("%[buf_size] &= 0xfff;\n" ::[buf_size] "+r"(buf_size):);
    char *buf;
    bpf_probe_read(&buf, sizeof(buf), &ctx->buf);

    zero = 0;
    struct syscall_write_event_t *event = bpf_map_lookup_elem(&write_buffer_heap, &zero);
    if (!event) {
      return 0;
    }
    event->attr.fd = ctx->fd;
    event->attr.bytes = ctx->count;
    event->attr.msg_size = buf_size;
    event->attr.event_type = kEventTypeSyscallWriteEvent;
    int size = bpf_probe_read_str(&event->msg, buf_size, buf);
    bpf_perf_event_output(ctx, &syscall_write_events, BPF_F_CURRENT_CPU, &event, sizeof(struct syscall_write_event_t)-MAX_MSG_SIZE+size);
    return 0;
}
```

verifier log:

```
 func#0 @0
0: R1=ctx(id=0,off=0,imm=0) R10=fp0
; int syscall__probe_write(struct sys_enter_read_write_ctx *ctx) {
0: (bf) r6 = r1
1: R1=ctx(id=0,off=0,imm=0) R6_w=ctx(id=0,off=0,imm=0) R10=fp0
; size_t buf_size = ctx->count & 0x3ff;
1: (79) r7 = *(u64 *)(r6 +24)
2: R1=ctx(id=0,off=0,imm=0) R6_w=ctx(id=0,off=0,imm=0) R7_w=inv(id=0) R10=fp0
; bpf_probe_read(&buf, sizeof(buf), &ctx->buf);
2: (bf) r3 = r6
3: R1=ctx(id=0,off=0,imm=0) R3_w=ctx(id=0,off=0,imm=0) R6_w=ctx(id=0,off=0,imm=0) R7_w=inv(id=0) R10=fp0
3: (07) r3 += 16
4: R1=ctx(id=0,off=0,imm=0) R3_w=ctx(id=0,off=16,imm=0) R6_w=ctx(id=0,off=0,imm=0) R7_w=inv(id=0) R10=fp0
4: (bf) r1 = r10
5: R1_w=fp0 R3_w=ctx(id=0,off=16,imm=0) R6_w=ctx(id=0,off=0,imm=0) R7_w=inv(id=0) R10=fp0
;
5: (07) r1 += -16
6: R1_w=fp-16 R3_w=ctx(id=0,off=16,imm=0) R6_w=ctx(id=0,off=0,imm=0) R7_w=inv(id=0) R10=fp0
; bpf_probe_read(&buf, sizeof(buf), &ctx->buf);
6: (b7) r2 = 8
7: R1_w=fp-16 R2_w=inv8 R3_w=ctx(id=0,off=16,imm=0) R6_w=ctx(id=0,off=0,imm=0) R7_w=inv(id=0) R10=fp0
7: (85) call bpf_probe_read#4
last_idx 7 first_idx 0
regs=4 stack=0 before 6: (b7) r2 = 8
8: R0_w=inv(id=0) R6_w=ctx(id=0,off=0,imm=0) R7_w=inv(id=0) R10=fp0 fp-16=mmmmmmmm
8: (b7) r1 = 0
9: R0_w=inv(id=0) R1_w=inv0 R6_w=ctx(id=0,off=0,imm=0) R7_w=inv(id=0) R10=fp0 fp-16=mmmmmmmm
; zero = 0;
9: (63) *(u32 *)(r10 -4) = r1
last_idx 9 first_idx 0
regs=2 stack=0 before 8: (b7) r1 = 0
10: R0_w=inv(id=0) R1_w=invP0 R6_w=ctx(id=0,off=0,imm=0) R7_w=inv(id=0) R10=fp0 fp-8=0000???? fp-16=mmmmmmmm
10: (bf) r2 = r10
11: R0_w=inv(id=0) R1_w=invP0 R2_w=fp0 R6_w=ctx(id=0,off=0,imm=0) R7_w=inv(id=0) R10=fp0 fp-8=0000???? fp-16=mmmmmmmm
;
11: (07) r2 += -4
12: R0_w=inv(id=0) R1_w=invP0 R2_w=fp-4 R6_w=ctx(id=0,off=0,imm=0) R7_w=inv(id=0) R10=fp0 fp-8=0000???? fp-16=mmmmmmmm
; struct syscall_write_event_t *event = bpf_map_lookup_elem(&write_buffer_heap, &zero);
12: (18) r1 = 0xffff88880710a200
14: R0_w=inv(id=0) R1_w=map_ptr(id=0,off=0,ks=4,vs=1040,imm=0) R2_w=fp-4 R6_w=ctx(id=0,off=0,imm=0) R7_w=inv(id=0) R10=fp0 fp-8=0000???? fp-16=mmmmmmmm
14: (85) call bpf_map_lookup_elem#1
15: R0=map_value_or_null(id=1,off=0,ks=4,vs=1040,imm=0) R6=ctx(id=0,off=0,imm=0) R7=inv(id=0) R10=fp0 fp-8=mmmm???? fp-16=mmmmmmmm
; struct syscall_write_event_t *event = bpf_map_lookup_elem(&write_buffer_heap, &zero);
15: (7b) *(u64 *)(r10 -24) = r0
16: R0=map_value_or_null(id=1,off=0,ks=4,vs=1040,imm=0) R6=ctx(id=0,off=0,imm=0) R7=inv(id=0) R10=fp0 fp-8=mmmm???? fp-16=mmmmmmmm fp-24_w=map_value_or_null
; if (!event) {
16: (15) if r0 == 0x0 goto pc+25
 R0=map_value(id=0,off=0,ks=4,vs=1040,imm=0) R6=ctx(id=0,off=0,imm=0) R7=inv(id=0) R10=fp0 fp-8=mmmm???? fp-16=mmmmmmmm fp-24_w=map_value
17: R0=map_value(id=0,off=0,ks=4,vs=1040,imm=0) R6=ctx(id=0,off=0,imm=0) R7=inv(id=0) R10=fp0 fp-8=mmmm???? fp-16=mmmmmmmm fp-24_w=map_value
; event->attr.fd = ctx->fd;
17: (61) r1 = *(u32 *)(r6 +12)
18: R0=map_value(id=0,off=0,ks=4,vs=1040,imm=0) R1_w=inv(id=0,umax_value=4294967295,var_off=(0x0; 0xffffffff)) R6=ctx(id=0,off=0,imm=0) R7=inv(id=0) R10=fp0 fp-8=mmmm???? fp-16=mmmmmmmm fp-24_w=map_value
; event->attr.fd = ctx->fd;
18: (63) *(u32 *)(r0 +4) = r1
 R0=map_value(id=0,off=0,ks=4,vs=1040,imm=0) R1_w=inv(id=0,umax_value=4294967295,var_off=(0x0; 0xffffffff)) R6=ctx(id=0,off=0,imm=0) R7=inv(id=0) R10=fp0 fp-8=mmmm???? fp-16=mmmmmmmm fp-24_w=map_value
19: R0=map_value(id=0,off=0,ks=4,vs=1040,imm=0) R1_w=inv(id=0,umax_value=4294967295,var_off=(0x0; 0xffffffff)) R6=ctx(id=0,off=0,imm=0) R7=inv(id=0) R10=fp0 fp-8=mmmm???? fp-16=mmmmmmmm fp-24_w=map_value
; event->attr.bytes = ctx->count;
19: (79) r1 = *(u64 *)(r6 +24)
20: R0=map_value(id=0,off=0,ks=4,vs=1040,imm=0) R1_w=inv(id=0) R6=ctx(id=0,off=0,imm=0) R7=inv(id=0) R10=fp0 fp-8=mmmm???? fp-16=mmmmmmmm fp-24_w=map_value
; event->attr.bytes = ctx->count;
20: (63) *(u32 *)(r0 +8) = r1
 R0=map_value(id=0,off=0,ks=4,vs=1040,imm=0) R1_w=inv(id=0) R6=ctx(id=0,off=0,imm=0) R7=inv(id=0) R10=fp0 fp-8=mmmm???? fp-16=mmmmmmmm fp-24_w=map_value
21: R0=map_value(id=0,off=0,ks=4,vs=1040,imm=0) R1_w=inv(id=0) R6=ctx(id=0,off=0,imm=0) R7=inv(id=0) R10=fp0 fp-8=mmmm???? fp-16=mmmmmmmm fp-24_w=map_value
21: (b7) r1 = 2
22: R0=map_value(id=0,off=0,ks=4,vs=1040,imm=0) R1_w=inv2 R6=ctx(id=0,off=0,imm=0) R7=inv(id=0) R10=fp0 fp-8=mmmm???? fp-16=mmmmmmmm fp-24_w=map_value
; event->attr.event_type = kEventTypeSyscallWriteEvent;
22: (63) *(u32 *)(r0 +0) = r1
 R0=map_value(id=0,off=0,ks=4,vs=1040,imm=0) R1_w=inv2 R6=ctx(id=0,off=0,imm=0) R7=inv(id=0) R10=fp0 fp-8=mmmm???? fp-16=mmmmmmmm fp-24_w=map_value
23: R0=map_value(id=0,off=0,ks=4,vs=1040,imm=0) R1_w=inv2 R6=ctx(id=0,off=0,imm=0) R7=inv(id=0) R10=fp0 fp-8=mmmm???? fp-16=mmmmmmmm fp-24_w=map_value
; event->attr.msg_size = buf_size;
23: (57) r7 &= 1023
24: R0=map_value(id=0,off=0,ks=4,vs=1040,imm=0) R1_w=inv2 R6=ctx(id=0,off=0,imm=0) R7_w=inv(id=0,umax_value=1023,var_off=(0x0; 0x3ff)) R10=fp0 fp-8=mmmm???? fp-16=mmmmmmmm fp-24_w=map_value
; event->attr.msg_size = buf_size;
24: (63) *(u32 *)(r0 +12) = r7
 R0=map_value(id=0,off=0,ks=4,vs=1040,imm=0) R1_w=inv2 R6=ctx(id=0,off=0,imm=0) R7_w=inv(id=0,umax_value=1023,var_off=(0x0; 0x3ff)) R10=fp0 fp-8=mmmm???? fp-16=mmmmmmmm fp-24_w=map_value
25: R0=map_value(id=0,off=0,ks=4,vs=1040,imm=0) R1_w=inv2 R6=ctx(id=0,off=0,imm=0) R7_w=inv(id=0,umax_value=1023,var_off=(0x0; 0x3ff)) R10=fp0 fp-8=mmmm???? fp-16=mmmmmmmm fp-24_w=map_value
; int size = bpf_probe_read_str(&event->msg, buf_size, buf);
25: (79) r3 = *(u64 *)(r10 -16)
26: R0=map_value(id=0,off=0,ks=4,vs=1040,imm=0) R1_w=inv2 R3_w=inv(id=0) R6=ctx(id=0,off=0,imm=0) R7_w=inv(id=0,umax_value=1023,var_off=(0x0; 0x3ff)) R10=fp0 fp-8=mmmm???? fp-16=mmmmmmmm fp-24_w=map_value
; int size = bpf_probe_read_str(&event->msg, buf_size, buf);
26: (07) r0 += 16
27: R0_w=map_value(id=0,off=16,ks=4,vs=1040,imm=0) R1_w=inv2 R3_w=inv(id=0) R6=ctx(id=0,off=0,imm=0) R7_w=inv(id=0,umax_value=1023,var_off=(0x0; 0x3ff)) R10=fp0 fp-8=mmmm???? fp-16=mmmmmmmm fp-24_w=map_value
; int size = bpf_probe_read_str(&event->msg, buf_size, buf);
27: (bf) r1 = r0
28: R0_w=map_value(id=0,off=16,ks=4,vs=1040,imm=0) R1_w=map_value(id=0,off=16,ks=4,vs=1040,imm=0) R3_w=inv(id=0) R6=ctx(id=0,off=0,imm=0) R7_w=inv(id=0,umax_value=1023,var_off=(0x0; 0x3ff)) R10=fp0 fp-8=mmmm???? fp-16=mmmmmmmm fp-24_w=map_value
28: (bf) r2 = r7
29: R0_w=map_value(id=0,off=16,ks=4,vs=1040,imm=0) R1_w=map_value(id=0,off=16,ks=4,vs=1040,imm=0) R2_w=inv(id=0,umax_value=1023,var_off=(0x0; 0x3ff)) R3_w=inv(id=0) R6=ctx(id=0,off=0,imm=0) R7_w=inv(id=0,umax_value=1023,var_off=(0x0; 0x3ff)) R10=fp0 fp-8=mmmm???? fp-16=mmmmmmmm fp-24_w=map_value
29: (85) call bpf_probe_read_str#45
 R0_w=map_value(id=0,off=16,ks=4,vs=1040,imm=0) R1_w=map_value(id=0,off=16,ks=4,vs=1040,imm=0) R2_w=inv(id=0,umax_value=1023,var_off=(0x0; 0x3ff)) R3_w=inv(id=0) R6=ctx(id=0,off=0,imm=0) R7_w=inv(id=0,umax_value=1023,var_off=(0x0; 0x3ff)) R10=fp0 fp-8=mmmm???? fp-16=mmmmmmmm fp-24_w=map_value
 R0_w=map_value(id=0,off=16,ks=4,vs=1040,imm=0) R1_w=map_value(id=0,off=16,ks=4,vs=1040,imm=0) R2_w=inv(id=0,umax_value=1023,var_off=(0x0; 0x3ff)) R3_w=inv(id=0) R6=ctx(id=0,off=0,imm=0) R7_w=inv(id=0,umax_value=1023,var_off=(0x0; 0x3ff)) R10=fp0 fp-8=mmmm???? fp-16=mmmmmmmm fp-24_w=map_value
last_idx 29 first_idx 15
regs=4 stack=0 before 28: (bf) r2 = r7
regs=80 stack=0 before 27: (bf) r1 = r0
regs=80 stack=0 before 26: (07) r0 += 16
regs=80 stack=0 before 25: (79) r3 = *(u64 *)(r10 -16)
regs=80 stack=0 before 24: (63) *(u32 *)(r0 +12) = r7
regs=80 stack=0 before 23: (57) r7 &= 1023
regs=80 stack=0 before 22: (63) *(u32 *)(r0 +0) = r1
regs=80 stack=0 before 21: (b7) r1 = 2
regs=80 stack=0 before 20: (63) *(u32 *)(r0 +8) = r1
regs=80 stack=0 before 19: (79) r1 = *(u64 *)(r6 +24)
regs=80 stack=0 before 18: (63) *(u32 *)(r0 +4) = r1
regs=80 stack=0 before 17: (61) r1 = *(u32 *)(r6 +12)
regs=80 stack=0 before 16: (15) if r0 == 0x0 goto pc+25
regs=80 stack=0 before 15: (7b) *(u64 *)(r10 -24) = r0
 R0_rw=map_value_or_null(id=1,off=0,ks=4,vs=1040,imm=0) R6_rw=ctx(id=0,off=0,imm=0) R7_rw=invP(id=0) R10=fp0 fp-8=mmmm???? fp-16_r=mmmmmmmm
parent didn't have regs=80 stack=0 marks
last_idx 14 first_idx 0
regs=80 stack=0 before 14: (85) call bpf_map_lookup_elem#1
regs=80 stack=0 before 12: (18) r1 = 0xffff88880710a200
regs=80 stack=0 before 11: (07) r2 += -4
regs=80 stack=0 before 10: (bf) r2 = r10
regs=80 stack=0 before 9: (63) *(u32 *)(r10 -4) = r1
regs=80 stack=0 before 8: (b7) r1 = 0
regs=80 stack=0 before 7: (85) call bpf_probe_read#4
regs=80 stack=0 before 6: (b7) r2 = 8
regs=80 stack=0 before 5: (07) r1 += -16
regs=80 stack=0 before 4: (bf) r1 = r10
regs=80 stack=0 before 3: (07) r3 += 16
regs=80 stack=0 before 2: (bf) r3 = r6
regs=80 stack=0 before 1: (79) r7 = *(u64 *)(r6 +24)
30: R0=inv(id=0,umax_value=1023,var_off=(0x0; 0x3ff)) R6=ctx(id=0,off=0,imm=0) R7=inv(id=0,umax_value=1023,var_off=(0x0; 0x3ff)) R10=fp0 fp-8=mmmm???? fp-16=mmmmmmmm fp-24=map_value
; bpf_perf_event_output(ctx, &syscall_write_events, BPF_F_CURRENT_CPU, &event, sizeof(struct syscall_write_event_t)-MAX_MSG_SIZE+size);
30: (67) r0 <<= 32
31: R0_w=inv(id=0,umax_value=4393751543808,var_off=(0x0; 0x3ff00000000)) R6=ctx(id=0,off=0,imm=0) R7=inv(id=0,umax_value=1023,var_off=(0x0; 0x3ff)) R10=fp0 fp-8=mmmm???? fp-16=mmmmmmmm fp-24=map_value
31: (c7) r0 s>>= 32
32: R0_w=inv(id=0,umax_value=1023,var_off=(0x0; 0x3ff)) R6=ctx(id=0,off=0,imm=0) R7=inv(id=0,umax_value=1023,var_off=(0x0; 0x3ff)) R10=fp0 fp-8=mmmm???? fp-16=mmmmmmmm fp-24=map_value
; bpf_perf_event_output(ctx, &syscall_write_events, BPF_F_CURRENT_CPU, &event, sizeof(struct syscall_write_event_t)-MAX_MSG_SIZE+size);
32: (07) r0 += 16
33: R0_w=inv(id=0,umin_value=16,umax_value=1039,var_off=(0x0; 0x7ff)) R6=ctx(id=0,off=0,imm=0) R7=inv(id=0,umax_value=1023,var_off=(0x0; 0x3ff)) R10=fp0 fp-8=mmmm???? fp-16=mmmmmmmm fp-24=map_value
33: (bf) r4 = r10
34: R0_w=inv(id=0,umin_value=16,umax_value=1039,var_off=(0x0; 0x7ff)) R4_w=fp0 R6=ctx(id=0,off=0,imm=0) R7=inv(id=0,umax_value=1023,var_off=(0x0; 0x3ff)) R10=fp0 fp-8=mmmm???? fp-16=mmmmmmmm fp-24=map_value
;
34: (07) r4 += -24
35: R0_w=inv(id=0,umin_value=16,umax_value=1039,var_off=(0x0; 0x7ff)) R4_w=fp-24 R6=ctx(id=0,off=0,imm=0) R7=inv(id=0,umax_value=1023,var_off=(0x0; 0x3ff)) R10=fp0 fp-8=mmmm???? fp-16=mmmmmmmm fp-24=map_value
; bpf_perf_event_output(ctx, &syscall_write_events, BPF_F_CURRENT_CPU, &event, sizeof(struct syscall_write_event_t)-MAX_MSG_SIZE+size);
35: (bf) r1 = r6
36: R0_w=inv(id=0,umin_value=16,umax_value=1039,var_off=(0x0; 0x7ff)) R1_w=ctx(id=0,off=0,imm=0) R4_w=fp-24 R6=ctx(id=0,off=0,imm=0) R7=inv(id=0,umax_value=1023,var_off=(0x0; 0x3ff)) R10=fp0 fp-8=mmmm???? fp-16=mmmmmmmm fp-24=map_value
36: (18) r2 = 0xffff888807109c00
38: R0_w=inv(id=0,umin_value=16,umax_value=1039,var_off=(0x0; 0x7ff)) R1_w=ctx(id=0,off=0,imm=0) R2_w=map_ptr(id=0,off=0,ks=4,vs=4,imm=0) R4_w=fp-24 R6=ctx(id=0,off=0,imm=0) R7=inv(id=0,umax_value=1023,var_off=(0x0; 0x3ff)) R10=fp0 fp-8=mmmm???? fp-16=mmmmmmmm fp-24=map_value
38: (18) r3 = 0xffffffff
40: R0_w=inv(id=0,umin_value=16,umax_value=1039,var_off=(0x0; 0x7ff)) R1_w=ctx(id=0,off=0,imm=0) R2_w=map_ptr(id=0,off=0,ks=4,vs=4,imm=0) R3_w=inv4294967295 R4_w=fp-24 R6=ctx(id=0,off=0,imm=0) R7=inv(id=0,umax_value=1023,var_off=(0x0; 0x3ff)) R10=fp0 fp-8=mmmm???? fp-16=mmmmmmmm fp-24=map_value
40: (bf) r5 = r0
41: R0_w=inv(id=0,umin_value=16,umax_value=1039,var_off=(0x0; 0x7ff)) R1_w=ctx(id=0,off=0,imm=0) R2_w=map_ptr(id=0,off=0,ks=4,vs=4,imm=0) R3_w=inv4294967295 R4_w=fp-24 R5_w=inv(id=0,umin_value=16,umax_value=1039,var_off=(0x0; 0x7ff)) R6=ctx(id=0,off=0,imm=0) R7=inv(id=0,umax_value=1023,var_off=(0x0; 0x3ff)) R10=fp0 fp-8=mmmm???? fp-16=mmmmmmmm fp-24=map_value
41: (85) call bpf_perf_event_output#25
invalid stack type R4 off=-24 access_size=1039
```

i'm really confused, hope someone can help out, Thanks!

Comment: Instead of that `llvm-objdump`, could you share the full verifier logs? It's currently unclear what variable `r2` refers to.

Comment: full verifier logs added

Comment: The first one looks really weird, as if there was a bug in the compiler. What version of LLVM/Clang did you use to compile the program?

Comment: clang version 15.0.7 (https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project.git 8dfdcc7b7bf66834a761bd8de445840ef68e4d1a)

Comment: Hm, the first one is probably also because of `&event` instead of `event`. Still weird that the compiler generates code that doesn't make any sense in that case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL;DR.** You want to pass a pointer to `bpf_perf_event_output`, not a pointer to a pointer.

---

**Verifier Error Explanation**

```
41: R0_w=inv(id=0,umin_value=16,umax_value=1039,var_off=(0x0; 0x7ff)) R1_w=ctx(id=0,off=0,imm=0) R2_w=map_ptr(id=0,off=0,ks=4,vs=4,imm=0) R3_w=inv4294967295 R4_w=fp-24 R5_w=inv(id=0,umin_value=16,umax_value=1039,var_off=(0x0; 0x7ff)) R6=ctx(id=0,off=0,imm=0) R7=inv(id=0,umax_value=1023,var_off=(0x0; 0x3ff)) R10=fp0 fp-8=mmmm???? fp-16=mmmmmmmm fp-24=map_value
41: (85) call bpf_perf_event_output#25
invalid stack type R4 off=-24 access_size=1039
```

Here the verifier complains that the fourth argument to `bpf_perf_event_output` is pointing to the stack with an access size that is way beyond the actual stack size. The fourth argument is `&event`.

---

**Root Cause**

The fourth argument to `bpf_perf_event_output` should be a pointer to the data to post on the ring buffer. Hence, you want to pass `event` as the argument, not `&event`.

Comment: really thankful! Then I found that the fifth parameter of `bpf_perf_event_output` is wrong, change it to `sizeof(event->attr) + buf_size` and load successfully